# Reset counter automatically after lstlinputlisting or lstlisting

Tags: listings, counters

I have a number of code examples annotated with a number set by a counter, `lstNoteCounter` and referred to in the text below the code:
My markup works, but it isn't convenient for a large document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
   basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, % Standardschrift
   escapechar=¢,
   language=python,
 }
\usepackage{pifont}     % dings for margin numbers
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{lstNoteCounter}
\newcommand{\lnnum}[1]{% Print pifont circled number for line label
\noindent
\ifcase#1%
% nothing for 0
\or\normalsize\ding{202}%
\or\normalsize\ding{203}%
\or\normalsize\ding{204}%
\or\normalsize\ding{205}%       % in practice, we continue to 9
\else{NUM TOO HIGH}%
\fi%
}

\newcommand*{\lnote}{%
\stepcounter{lstNoteCounter}\vbox{\llap{{\lnnum{\thelstNoteCounter}}\hskip 1em}}%
}

\newcommand*{\lnoteref} {%
\stepcounter{lstNoteCounter}{\lnnum{\thelstNoteCounter}\hskip 0.5em}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=lines]
¢\lnote¢def cosec(x):
    return 1/math.sin(x)

¢\lnote¢csc = cosec
print(csc(math.pi/3))
\end{lstlisting}
% I have to reset manually HERE:
\setcounter{lstNoteCounter}{0}

\lnoteref There is no \texttt{cosec} function in Python's \texttt{math} module, so we define one.

\lnoteref Python functions are objects so we can assign them to identifiers.

% I have to reset manually HERE:
\setcounter{lstNoteCounter}{0}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=lines]
¢\lnote¢def sec(x):
    return 1/math.cos(x)

¢\lnote¢print(sec(math.pi/3))
\end{lstlisting}

% I have to reset manually HERE:
\setcounter{lstNoteCounter}{0}

\lnoteref There is no \texttt{sec} function either, so define one.

\lnoteref Will print \texttt{2}.

\end{document}
```

How can I automatically reset `lstNoteCounter` before and after either the `lstlisting` or `lstinputlisting` environments so I don't have to issue the commands `\setcounter{lstNoteCounter}{0}` manually each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's better to use the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism. If you change your mind about the numbering, you just need to change the definition of `\lnnumding`. Linking the counter to `mocklisting` that's stepped at each call of `python` resets it to zero.

By setting labels you gain more flexibility (at the expense of having to provide a label).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pifont}     % dings for margin numbers

\lstset{
   basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, % Standardschrift
   escapechar=¢,
   language=python,
 }

\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]
 {\stepcounter{mocklisting}\lstset{#1}}
 {}

\newcounter{mocklisting}
\newcounter{lstNoteCounter}[mocklisting]
\renewcommand{\thelstNoteCounter}{\lnnumding{\arabic{lstNoteCounter}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\lnnumding}[1]{\mbox{\normalsize\ding{\number\numexpr201+#1}}}

\newcommand*{\lnote}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{lstNoteCounter}\label{#1}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\thelstNoteCounter\hspace{1em}}%
}

\newcommand*{\lnoteref}[1]{\ref{#1}\hspace{.5em}\ignorespaces}


\begin{document}

\begin{python}[frame=lines]
¢\lnote{A}¢def cosec(x):
    return 1/math.sin(x)

¢\lnote{B}¢csc = cosec
print(csc(math.pi/3))
\end{python}

\lnoteref{A} There is no \texttt{cosec} function in Python's \texttt{math} module,
so we define one.

\lnoteref{B} Python functions are objects so we can assign them to identifiers.

\begin{python}[frame=lines]
¢\lnote{C}¢def sec(x):
    return 1/math.cos(x)

¢\lnote{D}¢print(sec(math.pi/3))
\end{python}

\lnoteref{C} There is no \texttt{sec} function either, so define one.

\lnoteref{D} Will print \texttt{2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help: I'd like to go with your suggestion, but I'm getting stuck applying to to `\lstinputlisting` as well. How should I define a custom environment for this to work in the same way as `lstlisting`?

Comment: @xnx `\newcommand{\inputpython}[2][]{\stepcounter{mocklisting}\lstinputlisting[#1]{#2}}`

Answer (score 4):

The best way I think it is to define a new listing environment that does that at its beginning and at its end.

For example, let's call it `mylisting`:

```
\lstnewenvironment{mylisting}[1][]
{\lstset{%
   basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, % Standardschrift
   escapechar=¢,
   language=python,
   #1
 }%
\setcounter{lstNoteCounter}{0}}
{\setcounter{lstNoteCounter}{0}}
```

and in your document use `mylisting` instead of `lstlisting`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{mylisting}[1][]
{\lstset{%
   basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, % Standardschrift
   escapechar=¢,
   language=python,
   #1
 }%
\setcounter{lstNoteCounter}{0}}
{\setcounter{lstNoteCounter}{0}}

\usepackage{pifont}     % dings for margin numbers
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{lstNoteCounter}
\newcommand{\lnnum}[1]{% Print pifont circled number for line label
\noindent
\ifcase#1%
% nothing for 0
\or\normalsize\ding{202}%
\or\normalsize\ding{203}%
\or\normalsize\ding{204}%
\or\normalsize\ding{205}%       % in practice, we continue to 9
\else{NUM TOO HIGH}%
\fi%
}

\newcommand*{\lnote}{%
\stepcounter{lstNoteCounter}\vbox{\llap{{\lnnum{\thelstNoteCounter}}\hskip 1em}}%
}

\newcommand*{\lnoteref} {%
\stepcounter{lstNoteCounter}{\lnnum{\thelstNoteCounter}\hskip 0.5em}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}[frame=lines]
¢\lnote¢def cosec(x):
    return 1/math.sin(x)

¢\lnote¢csc = cosec
print(csc(math.pi/3))
\end{mylisting}

\lnoteref There is no \texttt{cosec} function in Python's \texttt{math} module, so we define one.

\lnoteref Python functions are objects so we can assign them to identifiers.

\begin{mylisting}[frame=lines]
¢\lnote¢def sec(x):
    return 1/math.cos(x)

¢\lnote¢print(sec(math.pi/3))
\end{mylisting}

\lnoteref There is no \texttt{sec} function either, so define one.

\lnoteref Will print \texttt{2}.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]